# How do I determine if a lat/long point is within a polygon?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a shapefile of all the counties that make up my state. Using the shapefile (which contains geometric for the district polygons) I was able to use geopandas to plot the shapes in a figure. I have some addresses that I have geocoded into latitude and longitude coordinates and I'd like to be able to determine which county (or polygon) the coordinates are within. I see that geopandas has a `within` function, but I don't quite understand how to use it.

The end goal will be for a user to input and address and the program returns the county name. There are only a few dozen counties so I was thinking of using a for loop to iterate through the rows and check each polygon to see if the provided coordinate lies within.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `shapely`'s [documentations](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#:%7E:text=interior%20of%20object.-,This%20predicate%20applies%20to%20all%20types,-%2C%20and%20is%20inverse) will be helpful to understand how `within` function works. But, i order to give you more insight, try code below:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
pol = Polygon([[0,0], [0,2], [2,2], [2,0]])
pnt = Point(1,1)
pnt.within(pol)
```

result:

```
True
```

##### Explanation

`pol` is a rectangle(square) with 2 units on each side. We used created a new point with coordinates of `(1,1)` which locates exactly in the center of the square. Using `within` function on the `Point` object and giving the `Polygon` as an argument to this function you can check if the point is in the area or not.

Comment: Ohh it's a shapely function! I had been searching through the wrong documentation. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @arctic_radar `GeoSeries` has a within function too of which I am not very aware. But shapely should do the job for you as well.