# Detect which point is inside of which polygon (Python)

Tags: polygon, geopandas, points

I have a shapefile of points and another shapefile of polygons.

My goal is to check which point is inside which polygon, so that I can change the name of the point with respect to the name of the polygon.

How can I do this

Comment: `sjoin()` example fully covered in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229844/how-do-i-determine-if-a-lat-long-point-is-within-a-polygon/71234065#71234065

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link each point in one GeoPandas dataframe to polygons in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513123/link-each-point-in-one-geopandas-dataframe-to-polygons-in-another-dataframe)

Comment: [geopandas-point-in-polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097742/geopandas-point-in-polygon) is 10 lines, without `sjoin`